# mapping between two tables using EF Core Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I am looking to try to build the schema and relation between below two models  using `EF Core code first` like below

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
}
```

Could any one please suggest is there any changes need to be done to the above models (Status & Order) to  get the query results like below

```
     OrderID    description    status
       1            test1      approved
       2            test2      rejected
```

Comment: could any one please suggest whether the above model mapping between those are correct if want to get the results like grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your navigation property "Status" to virtual property like:

```
public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status status { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do `Order.Status.Status` for each row while displaying

Comment: I dont want to insert details into status table for each order when i am going to insert into order table i do want to insert status id into order table... Could you please let me know for this condition the above model is sufficient or not

Comment: I just want to insert the status ID in order table for this your model criteria will work

Answer (score 1):

I write code below and get next results.

> 1d7336aa-c144-4ca4-d2de-08d76cae93ab Description approved

```
public static void Main()
{
    ShowData(AddData());
}

public static void ShowData(Guid orderId)
{
    using var context = new OrderContext();
    Console.WriteLine(context.Orders
        .Where(x => x.Id == orderId)
        .First()
        .ToString());
}

public static Guid AddData()
{
    using var context = new OrderContext();
    var status = new Status()
    {
        StatusName = "approved"
    };
    var order = new Order()
    {
        Description = "Description",
        Name = "Name",
        OrderStatus = status
    };

    context.Orders.Add(order);

    context.SaveChanges();

    return order.Id;
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{StatusName}";
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Status OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id} {Description} {OrderStatus}";
    }
}
```

I think you shoudn't change anything except adding virtual modificatitor to OrderStatus.